# Heroku PostgreSQL data center

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I have a prospective customer from Canada who wants to use my application deployed on Heroku. They have strict requirement that all the data must be stored inside the Canada region. I know Heroku does not offer any data center in Canada but is there any work around or any option to host the PostgreSQL Database in Canada?

My application already deployed on Heroku region(US). Any help would be appreciated.

Heroku Ticket: https://help.heroku.com/sharing/c6d20548-5670-4b2c-81bd-5def14c30be9

Comment: (Note that your Heroku ticket is not available publicly. That's a dead link to everybody but you.)

Answer (score 0):

> is there any work around or any option to host the PostgreSQL Database in Canada?

Sure: just use a hosted database service *in* Canada. But Heroku won't manage it for you.

[Amazon RDS is currently available in Canada Central](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.RegionsAndAvailabilityZones.html). [Azure Database for PostgreSQL is currently available in Canada Central and Canada East](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/postgresql/server/). I'm sure there are other options. Provision your own database on a service hosted in Canada and point your application to it, e.g. by setting an environment variable.

But be careful with this:

> They have strict requirement that all the data must be stored inside the Canada region

How "strict" is this requirement, and how is it defined? If your application is running on Heroku, their data will be in memory in the USA. And depending how your application is built there may be other concerns, e.g. with data in queues or caches etc...

Plus, both Amazon and Microsoft are American countries, potentially subject to American data access laws.

I suggest having an open conversation with your client to ensure that you are able to meet their needs. We're not your client so it's impossible to know whether hosting your database in Canada is sufficient.